# Why when I make a ping test from python does it have a different response to in windows cmd?

Tags: python, cmd, subprocess, ping

When I use the command `ping -l 1 -n 1 -w 750 google.com` in windows cmd it gives me a ping around 10ms. When I test it using python with the following code it regularly detects a timeout by beeping and printing despite the timeout being 750ms.

```
import subprocess
import winsound
import datetime
while 1:
    try:
        subprocess.check_output(['ping', '-l', '1', '-n', '1', '-w', '750', 'google.com'])
    except:
        print("cut at:", datetime.datetime.now())
        winsound.Beep(250, 500)
```

The exception that is raised is:

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ping', '-l', '1', '-n', '1', '-w', '750', 'google.com']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Why does it have such a different response and is there a way I can make the code detect an internet cut out more reliably?

Comment: Insert the line `raise` as the first line of the `except` clause and see what the exception being thrown actually is.

Comment: thanks, I've added that to the question.

Comment: On my Linux machine I am not able to replicate this. It gives me the same time and output.

Comment: My guess: Your anti-virus and/or firewall settings don't allow this. Guess2: You are running the two tests as different users or different privilege levels. Try temporarily disabling the A/V and firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Because it is in an infinite while loop, it would be pinging google many times a second and their dos prevention would probably notice this and prevent more requests causing the timeout. It was easily fixed with `time.sleep(1)` in the try part.